# TreeMap sorting by day of the week, not day of the month

Tags: java, collections

I have a `TreeMap`, however, it is not sorting correctly. It is also missing some values but I believe it's because the `Hashmap` sees multiple days of the week and takes them out.

Here is my code:

```
public Map<Date, String> findDates() throws ParseException {
    TypedQuery<InstallationDate> query = em.createNamedQuery("InstallationDate.findDates", InstallationDate.class);

    List<InstallationDate> dates = null;
    try {
        dates = query.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        nre.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    Map<Date, String> installationDates = null;
    if (dates != null) {
        installationDates = new HashMap<Date, String>();
        for (InstallationDate date : dates) {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EE dd MMMMMMMMM YYYY");
            installationDates.put(f.parse(date.getInstallation_day()), date.getInstallation_day());

        }
    }
    Map<Date, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Date, String>(installationDates);
    return treeMap;
}
```

What I get is this:

```
Sunday 15 November 2015
Monday 16 November 2015 
Tuesday 10 November 2015
Wednesday 11 November 2015
Thursday 12 November 2015
Friday 13 November 2015
Saturday 14 November 2015
```

But What I need is this:

```
Tuesday 3 November 2015
Wednesday 4 November 2015
Thursday 5 November 2015
Friday 6 November 2015
```

... and so on until `Monday 16 November 2015`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean `what I get`? Where are you printing this?

Comment: I think we need to see the code for `InstallationDate` so we can see how its sort order is defined. Your `TreeMap` will use the default comparison.

Comment: @IsmaiBadawi Sorry i will show that.

Comment: Try over-riding the default comparator.

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to write your own Comparator**

You didn't show the code of InstallationDate class.

I've simplified your code and suggest you to focus on `compare()` method of `Comparator` class.

```
public static void findDates() throws ParseException {

        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

        dates.add(format.parse("November 15 2015"));
        dates.add(format.parse("November 16 2015"));
        dates.add(format.parse("November 10 2015"));
        dates.add(format.parse("November 11 2015"));
        dates.add(format.parse("November 12 2015"));
        dates.add(format.parse("November 13 2015"));
        dates.add(format.parse("November 14 2015"));

        Map<Date, String> installationDates = new HashMap<Date, String>();

        for (Date date : dates) {
            String day = new Integer(date.getDay()).toString();
            installationDates.put(date, day);
        }

        Map<Date, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Date, String>(
                new Comparator<Date>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Date date1, Date date2) {
                        return date1.compareTo(date2);
                    }
                });

        treeMap.putAll(installationDates);
        for (Entry<Date, String> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EE dd MMMMMMMMM YYYY",Locale.ENGLISH);
            System.out.println(f.format(entry.getKey()) );
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
Tue 10 November 2015
Wed 11 November 2015
Thu 12 November 2015
Fri 13 November 2015
Sat 14 November 2015
Sun 15 November 2015
Mon 16 November 2015
```

Comment: `Date` implements `Comparable<Date>`, and `TreeMap` will use that ordering. No need to implement a comparator.